# Extracting dictionary with a subset of values from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, extract, sublist

I have a dictionary and want to remove certain values in `bad_list` from its value list, and return the remainder. Here is the code:

```
d = {1: ['a', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['b'], 5: ['e']}

bad_list = ['d','e']

ad = {k:d[k].remove(i) for k in d.keys() for sublist in d[k] for i in sublist if i in bad_list}

print 'd =', d

print 'ad =', ad
```

Unfortunately what that does is it changes the values in `d` permanently, and returns `None` for values in ad.

```
d =  {1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b'], 5: []}

ad =  {1: None, 5: None}
```

How can I get a dictionary that looks like this:

```
new_dict = {1: ['a','c'], 2:['b']}
```

without looping through? I have a much larger dictionary to deal with, and I'd like to do it in the most efficient way.

Comment: As the answers have told you, just use a list comprehension. Why it doesn't work on your case? Because the function `remove` removes an item from your list and returns `None`, and according to your description, that's exactly what you don't want, to remove an item.... don't use `remove`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it without loop:

```
d = dict((key, [x for x in value if x not in bad_list]) for key, value in d.iteritems())
```

or with filter:

```
d = dict((key, filter(lambda x: x not in bad_list, d[key])) for key in d)
```

UPDATE

To exclude empty values:

```
d = dict((key, list(x)) for key in d for x in [set(d[key]).difference(bad_list)] if x)
```

Comment: He seems to want the empty `5` list filtered out too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just use 'list comprehension', this one liner works, thought I find if ugly.

```
ad = {k:v for k,v in {k:[i for i in v if i not in bad_list] for k,v in d.items()}.items() if v}
```

I'd better use a for loop.

```
ad2 = dict()
for k,v in d.items():
    _data_ = [item for item in v if item not in bad_list]
    if _data_:
        ad2[k]=_data_
```

Output:

```
print 'd =', d
print 'ad =', ad
print 'ad2=', ad2

>d = {1: ['a', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['b'], 5: ['e']}
>ad = {1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b']}
>ad2= {1: ['a', 'c'], 2: ['b']}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if the ad2 construction via a for loop takes the same time as the one-line version that uses list comprehension? I wanted to stay away from looping through every item, if possible, since I have a much larger dictionary to deal with. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea, you'd have to time it.

Comment: It looks like the loop is a bit faster: https://repl.it/BfBe . https://repl.it/BfBg

Answer (score 0):

The following code written in Python 3.5 appears to do as requested in your question. Minimal change should be required for it to work with Python 2.x instead. Just use `print` statements instead of functions.

```
d = {1: ['a', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['b'], 5: ['e']}
bad_list = ['d', 'e']
ad = {a: b for a, b in ((a, [c for c in b if c not in bad_list]) for a, b in d.items()) if b}
print('d =', d)
print('ad =', ad)
```